# Parallel magnetic circuit with 2 air gaps

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetics, magnetic-flux

I have the following ferromagnetic core.

- N = 300
- core thickness = 5 cm
- relative permeability = 2000
- the air gap's efective area rises 5%.
- 1 A going through the coil

I need to know the flux going through each of the 2 columns of the core.

To calculate that, I assumed that the Magnetomotive force of both columns is equal, because they have the same measures, and just tried to calculate the flux by dividing the MMF by the reluctance of each column.

I calculated the reluctances of the column and airgaps. (R = l/u.A)

- R columns = 0,37/(2000x4pix10^-7x0,0035) = 42062  (A = 7x5 = 35cm2)
- R airgap1 = 0,0007/(4pix10^-7x3,675x10^-3) = 151576 (A = 1,05x0,0035 = 3,675x10^-3 m2)
- R airgap2 = 0,0005/(4pix10^-7x3,675x10^-3) = 108268

I used those calculations to calculate the reluctance of each column by adding the air gap's reluctance to the reluctance of the column.

- Rcolumn1 = Rairgap1 + Rcolumn = 151576 + 42062 = 193638
- Rcolumn2 = Rairgap2 + Rcolumn = 108268 + 42062 = 150330

Then i calculated the flux in each column: (Flux = MMF/R)

- Flux1 = 300/193638 = 1,54X10^-3
- Flux2 = 300/150330 = 1,99x10^-3

I had doubts on this because then i calculated the total flux using the sum of all reluctances:

- Rtotal = 42062 + 151576 + 108268 = 301906
- FluxTot = 300/301906 = 9,936x10^-4

And it doesn't match the sum of the fluxes in the 2 columns: 1,54X10^-3 + 1,99x10^-3 = 3,53x10^-3

I don't know what I'm doing wrong or if I am thinking the right way.

[image]

Comment: Are you unable to calculate the reluctance for each path? You need to show some effort at finding a solution when wanting homework questions answering. What does FMM mean? Do you mean MMF? I think you mean reluctance rather than resistance?

Comment: I calculated the reluctances (The reluctance for the columns = 42062, for the first air gap = 151576 and for the second = 108268), Then to calculate the flux on the first column for example, i divided FMM (300) by the sum of the air gap reluctance with the column reluctance.  I'm not looking for the final answers, i just wanted to know if i am thinking the right way, or if it is completly wrong,. I explained my thoughts on this problem, just wanted some feedback. Yes i mean MMF, and reluctance.

Comment: You need to put this information in the question and you should show a reluctance circuit diagram.

Comment: Please use the full term for MMF at least once, to make it clear what abbreviation you're referring to. Edit the question to add all the necessary information.

Comment: I edited the question and tried to explain in a better way my thoughs on this problem. I hope you can help me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your thinking to calculate the flux in the two columns is conceptually correct. I'm not sure about all the details, it's not clear to me whether you are using the correct lengths, but, you say you are not looking for final answers.

The biggest numerical error occurs when you come to check your work by calculating the total flux based on the "sum of all reluctances".

The Rcolumn1/2 legs are in parallel, so you need the parallel (you've actually used the word parallel in your title!), not the series addition of these. Using the calculated figures you give for the legs and airgaps ...

Rlegs = 150k // 194k = 85k

To this you should add an additional Rcolumn for the central leg in series + 42k = 127k

Now your flux total is 300/127k = 2.4m

That's still not the 3.53m that you compute as the sum of the legs, but it's a lot closer than it was.

If I neglect the R of the central leg and do your sum again, the flux total is 300/85k = 3.5m, bang on.

This is still not the correct answer, as you have been sloppy about measuring the lengths of your legs 1 and 2. You have only added a single 42k (representing 370mm of iron) to the airgap R when I can see at least 900mm of iron in series with it.

Note that I had to neglect the R of the central leg to arrive at your answer. This hints at a more subtle conceptual error. The R of the central leg is 'shared' between the two gapped legs, and until you know how the flux splits, you don't know how much to apportion to each. Often when we do this kind of calculation, the  airgaps dominate the R, and that of the iron can be neglected. This is not the case here, and so you must take care of all the iron. The simplest way to do it would be to assume an initial split to the flux, either 50-50 or pro-rata with the airgaps, it doesn't much matter, and then iterate to arrive at a more accurate split, it should converge quickly.

(edit) the answer to your comment question

> I only added 42k once, because i thought that we only add different R when the measures of the columns are different. Therefor how many 42k should i have considered? I also don't understand which 900mm you're talking about

needs a diagram, so I'll answer it here

[image]

Working between points A and B, the left hand path includes the following (let's assume that the distance into and out of the corner is 7 cms) 37 cms to the top left hand corner, 37 cms to the bottom left hand corner passing through the 0.7 mm airgap, and a further 37 cms to point B. That's a total path length of 0.7 mm air + 1.11 m of iron (that's the 'at least 900 mm' I'm talking about). You can do a similar sum for the right hand path from A to B through the 0.5 mm airgap.

Calculate the R for each path, and put them in parallel.

Now if you had all of the N=300 available for pushing flux through those two paths, you could stop there. But you don't. The leg from B to A through the coil has its own 37 cm iron path. With your small airgaps, this is significant, and it reduces the MMF available between A and B through the outer legs. Depending on the accuracy you need, you could neglect or include this extra series R when calculating the individual and total fluxes.

(/edit)

Comment: I only added 42k once, because i thought that we only add different R when the measures of the columns are different. Therefor how many 42k should i have considered? I also don't understand which 900mm you're talking about.

Comment: @Aleat see the update to my answer